# Go 1.12 modules: local import in non-local import

Tags: go

I'm currently using Go 1.12 modules and really tired about importing.

I'm making the rest-api using gin(web microservices) and gorm(golang orm). Everything still ok while working in golang modules. But getting trouble with local packages importing

The directory tree:

[image: project tree]

The go.mod:

```
module github.com/Aragami1408/go-gorm

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.4.0
    github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.9
    github.com/lib/pq v1.1.1
    github.com/satori/go.uuid v1.2.0
)
```

The db.go:

```golang
package db

//code below...
```

The tasks.go:

```golang
package task

import (
    "../db"
)
```

But when I run and still get this error:

`local import "../db" in non-local package`

I've searched a lot on google and nothing helps

Answer (score 5):

From "[Do modules work with relative imports like import "./subdir"?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#do-modules-work-with-relative-imports-like-import-subdir)"

> In modules, there finally is a name for the subdirectory.
>
> If the parent directory says "`module m`" then the subdirectory is imported as "`m/subdir`", no longer "`./subdir`".

In your case:

```
import "github.com/Aragami1408/go-gorm/db"
# or maybe
import "go-gorm/db"
```

This assumes, as [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591936/go-1-12-modules-local-import-in-non-local-import/56591962#comment99888910_56591962) by [Silvio Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3944680/silvio-lucas), that you [have `set GO111MODULE=on`](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-use-modules).

Comment: both woth works. In other way, the new error: unknown import path "go-gorm/db": cannot find module providing package go-gorm/db

Comment: @HarryCoder Do you have an environment variable GOPATH set? If so, make sure to unset it/remove it.

Comment: @HarryCoder you need to set GO111MODULE=on variable as well.

Comment: @SilvioLucas I totally did

Answer (score 2):

If you are using go modules you can replace your package by a local one using:

```
go mod edit -replace github.com/username/project=/localpath
```

then just call

```
go get github.com/username/project
```

and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

When migrating to go as "package manager", you may create the file `go mod` using the command :

```bash
go mod init myhost/myrepo/mymodule
```

Then the file will be created `go.mod` will be created :

```
module myhost/myrepo/mymodule

go 1.15
```

Now you can leverage this file to list your dependencies to other modules :

```bash
# i.e: your module mymodule depends on github.com/gorilla/mux
go get github.com/gorilla/mux
```

You run it? then check again the content of `go.mod`

```
module myhost/myrepo/mymodule

go 1.15

require (
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.4
)
```

### You are happy because you leverage the package manager features and you are managing dependencies like a Boss.

#### However,...

However, you forget that you need to maintain all go files which imports directories with relative paths.

example :

if you have `main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "./router" // !! RELATIVE PATH
)
```

You must migrate also by replacing the relative path with `[module-name]/relative-path`. in this case, it must become :

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "myhost/myrepo/mymodule/router" // !!  No more RELATIVE PATH
)
```